# Python urllib2 Errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, gevent

I have a long list of URLs I need to open for my service. Whenever I attempt to open this entire list, I receive many errors such as this when I initiate the program: `[Errno 24] Too many open files`. I am using urllib2 and gevent.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: need to show some code. sscce.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Gevent.pool](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html) to only open a certain amount of urls at a time then reuse those greenlets when thay have opened a url.

Answer (score 0):

As we still don't know what you exactly do, I can only guess: you are opening many URLs at once, and only then you try to read them. Instead, you should/could open-read-close them and then advance to the next one.

Alternatively, you could create a concurrency capable URL loader: open *some* urls and try to read them concurrently. After closing one, you can start opening the next. If you limit that to 5 or 10 at once, you shouldn't get a problem any longer.